# Right triangle legs and their sum

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The length of each side of a certain right triangle is the reciprocal of a different integer. What is the least possible sum of these three integers?

I used sides 3, 4, 5 for the integer values and add those integers to return a final value of 12 as my answer.

However, the answer appears to be 47.

Can anybody please explain to me why 12 is not the correct answer?

Thank you.

Comment: $\left(\frac 13, \frac 14,\frac 15\right)$ is not a right triangle.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to determine the right integers for this specific problem?

Comment: I don't see a quick trick, which of course doesn't mean there isn't one.  Smallest one I found with some fairly random searching is $(100,75,60)$ but nothing in what I did was guaranteed to find the smallest example.

Comment: Oh, of course:   $(20,15,12)$ works and that matches your $47$.  But again, I am just searching  numerically...I haven't tried to analyze what the solutions should look like.

Answer (score 1):

To aid in a numerical search:

Assume $(a,b,c)$ is as desired.  That is, assume that $$\frac 1{a^2}+\frac 1{b^2}=\frac 1{c^2}$$

It follows immediately that $$(bc)^2+(ac)^2=(ab)^2$$

From which we conclude that $(bc, ac, ab)$ is a Pythagorean triple.

Now it is a simple matter of searching through the Pythagorean triples until we find one of the desired form.  It turns out that $(a,b,c)=(20,15,12)$ is the least example.  It is associated with the Pythagorean triple $$(180, 240, 300)=60\times (3,4,5)$$

To elaborate on the search:  If $(A,B,C)$ is a Pythagorean triple, we try to solve $$A=bc\quad B=ac\quad C=ab$$
Multiplying these together yields $$ABC=(abc)^2\implies abc=\sqrt {ABC}$$

So of course, we need $\sqrt {ABC}\in \mathbb N$.  If it is, then it is easy to finish, since, e.g., $$a=\frac {abc}{bc}=\frac {\sqrt {ABC}}{A}$$  which, a priori, is at least rational. Of course, in each case we must check that it too is a natural number.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and aid!

Comment: Well, I expect there's a clever non-search method, but in the meantime, this gets the job done.

Answer (score 0):

HINT.-I have a way to go direct to the solution but it is tedious and difficult maybe.

Let $a\lt b\lt c$ with $\dfrac{1}{c^2}+\dfrac{1}{b^2}=\dfrac{1}{a^2}$ so $(ab)^2+(ac)^2=(bc)^2$ Then
$$ab=x^2-y^2\\ac=2xy\\bc=x^2+y^2$$ It follows
$$a^2=\frac{2xy(x^2-y^2)}{x^2+y^2}\text { and }b^2+c^2=\frac{(x^2+y^2)^3}{2xy(x^2-y^2)}$$ Now  instead of minimizing $(a + b + c)$ we minimize $(a + b + c)^2$,   that is to say we find the minimum of the function 
$$f(x,y)=\frac{2xy(x^2-y^2)}{x^2+y^2}+\frac{(x^2+y^2)^3}{2xy(x^2-y^2)}+2(x^2+xy)$$

Answer (score 0):

Your error is that the sides of the legs are not supposed to be integers but reciprocals of integers.

We need:

$(\frac 1m)^2 + (\frac 1n)^2 = (\frac 1p)^2$

If we multiply each term by the least common multiple of $m,n,p$, let's call it $L$, we get:

$(\frac Lm)^2 + (\frac Ln)^2 = (\frac Lp)^2$.  It's easy to verify these integers are relatively prime and $\frac Lm,\frac Ln, \frac Lp$ are a primitive pythagorean triplet.

If we let $\frac Lm = a; \frac Ln = b; \frac Lp = c$ we get that $m = bc; n = ac;$ and $p=ab$.

As $3,4,5$ is the smallest primitive pythagorean triplet it makes sense that $m = 20$ and $n= 15$ and $c= 12$ will be the smallest integers so that $(\frac 1m)^2 + (\frac 1n)^2 = (\frac 1p)^2$.